# Sequences and series with known variable

Tags: sequences-and-series

the fourth term in an arithmetic sequence are $ x+y , x-y ,xy, and$ $x/y$
in that order. WHat is the fifth term.

My attempt:
i have used the term of

$a,b,c$ equal to $2b=a+c$

but it shows no result. i only get variables only instead real number. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

From the first two terms the difference is $-2y$, so $xy=x-3y$ or $y=\frac{x}{x+3}$. So finally, $x+3=\frac{x}{y}=xy-2y=\frac{x(x-2)}{x+3}$, so $x=-\frac{9}{8}$ and hence $y=-\frac{3}{5}$. So the progression is $-\frac{69}{40},-\frac{21}{40},\frac{27}{40},\frac{75}{40}=\frac{15}{8}$. The fifth term is $\frac{123}{40}$.

Comment: The progression is right, but the question asked for the fifth term :-)

Comment: @joriki Oops. Fixed. Thanks.